# Ensure user is on master before running "npm version"

Tags: git, npm

I'm looking for a way to ensure the user running `npm version` is working on the `master` branch.

My thought is to use an npm `preversion` script, I just don't know what to place there.

```
"scripts": {
    "preversion": "exit with status code 0 only if `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` is `master`"
}
```

Ideally solution is cross-platform. Users are on Windows, but if the solution requires running `npm version` from git bash in order to be more "linuxy", that'd be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us, the solution was to actually just do `git checkout master`.

```
"scripts": {
  "preversion": "git checkout master"
}
```